# ASP/MVC - Switch a partial view in javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, razor, partial-views

I have table on my view page. One of the cells has an ID (say "x").
When a certain button is clicked a JS function is called, and the purpose is to dynamically change the partial view contained inside that cell using the code:

```
$("#X")[0].innerHTML = @Html.Partial("PartialViewName");
```

It works perfectly on firefox, but not in IE8. Also, FIY,the partial view is an AJAX form.

Comment: trying using quotes for setting the innerHTML value like this : `$("#X")[0].innerHTML = "@Html.Partial("PartialViewName")";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the partial view by ajax like this using [Jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/),

```
$("#X").load(@Url.Action("action","controller"));
```

and in the controller you have to return the partial view like this,

```
public ActionResult Action(){  
    return PartialView('PartialViewName')
}
```

Comment: It works very well, although I'd still like to know what is the "best practice" way to do that using MVC without using jquery load(). Thanks!

Comment: If you want to load it dynamically via ajax you can use JQuery `get`, `post` , `load` methods as you want. And if you do not want to load it  like that (if it is not heavy to load at the initial page load ) you can just hide that content when page loads. And then oyu can show it when user clicks the button.